# Haskell decrement function

Tags: haskell, recursion, type-inference

I am trying to learn Haskell, this is my very first approach at functional programming. I'm having some trouble creating a function that takes a number as input and prints that number one by one recursively, until 0.

```
printDescending n = if n > 0
                        then printDescending n - 1 return n
                        else return n - 1
```

I want to be able to do `printDescending 20` and have it output 20, 19, 18...2, 1, 0. But I'm getting this error:

```
>     • Non type-variable argument
>         in the constraint: Num ((a -> m a) -> a1 -> m1 a1)
>       (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
>     • When checking the inferred type
>         printDescending :: forall (m :: * -> *) a (m1 :: * -> *) a1.
>                            (Ord a1, Num ((a -> m a) -> a1 -> m1 a1), Num (m1 a1), Num a1,
>                             Monad m1, Monad m) =>
>                            a1 -> m1 a1 Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I think it may be my syntax. Anyone have some insight?

Comment: You need a print statement. http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output It should print the current number, and then call with `n - 1` if `n > 0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have shown:

```
printDescending n = if n > 0
                    then printDescending n - 1 return n
                    else return n - 1
```

Lets first look at how this is parsed:

```
printDescending n = if n > 0
                    then (printDescending n) - (1 return n)
                    else (return n) - 1
```

Probably not what you intended, huh?  Notice the infix operators, such as `-` bind less tightly than function application.  Also see how 'return' is not special - it's also just function application.  Finally, you didn't actually include a call to any sort of `print` command so no matter what language you are using I wouldn't expect this to function.

Fixing these issues, let's first provide a type signature (which is somewhat like a function prototype in C):

```
printDescending :: Int -> IO ()
```

So `printDecending` accepts one argument, an `Int`, and does some IO.  the `()` is called "unit" and for the first lesson of a programmer who knows C you should be able to mentally think of that as `void` and be OK.

Now how about the body? Well your `if` statement was fine:

```
printDescending n =
    if n > 0
      then  ...
      else...
```

The `else` statement was a little weird.  Even fixing the parsing, why would you want `0-1`?  Let's just return unit:

```
printDescending n =
    if n > 0
      then ...
      else return ()
```

Now for the `then` branch you want two things really.  1. print the value 2. recursively call printDecending on the next smallest value.  There is one bit of notation, `do`, that we'll use to sequence two IO operations but beyond that these two tasks translate to commands directly:

```
printDescending n =
    if n > 0
      then do print n
              printDescending (n - 1)
      else return ()
```

Now lets do one more step.  Since this isn't C/Java/etc and is a functional language then people will expect a declarative style.  To that end, let's declare printDescending using guards instead of an if statement:

```
printDescending n
    | n > 0 = do print n
                 printDescending (n-1)
    | otherwise = return ()
```

**Alternatives**

Now I'm going to present some alternatives, just for exemplification.

If you don't care about negative values then we could just terminate on zero with something like:

```
printDescending 0 = return ()
printDescending n =
     do print n
        printDescending (n-1)
```

Or we can use list comprehension to build a list of the values then perform `print` on each element of the list.  We can do this with `forM_` (see also the more idiomatic `mapM_`) which executes an operation on each element of the list and throws away the results, returning unit.

```
printDescending n = forM_ [n,n-1..1] print
```

Finally, if you want to have more rapid exchanges then consider joining the #haskell channel on irc.freenode.net.  There's a great group there and it's where many of the Haskell programmers I know got their start.

Comment: For the first example, you'll need `n >= 0`

Comment: FYI: your alternative using an enumeration is printing numbers in *ascending* order not descending. You should reverse that list first.

Comment: @gallais Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Another alternative is to use `*>` directly instead of introducing `do` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Thomas' detailed answer, I get the feeling that the following is what you were going for:

```
printDescending :: Integer -> IO ()
printDescending n = do
  print n
  if n > 0
     then printDescending (n - 1)
     else return ()
```

Admittedly, the `return ()` may seem strange at first.

A more functional approach might be something like this:

```
printDescending :: Integer -> IO ()
printDescending n = mapM_ print [n, (n-1) .. 0]
```

A quick tip: I'd recommend adding the function signature (if you know what it is) as it will help guide the compiler's error messages.

Comment: Indeed, the main difference between Steven and my answer is the printing of zero (or not).